# How to retrieve duplicate data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

```
$id = [
  0 => 604
  1 => 604
  2 => 550
]

$data = Parent_product::select('name', 'product_id')->whereIn('product_id', $ids)                                
                       ->get()->toArray();

Result
[
 [
   "name" => "Tomato",
   "product_id" => 604
 ],
 [
   "name" => "Patato",
   "product_id" => 550
 ]
]
```

The `$id` contains two `604` however the result only returned one record. How to make it return the duplicate result by using whereIn?

```
Expected result
[
 [
   "name" => "Tomato",
   "product_id" => 604
 ],
 [
   "name" => "Tomato",
   "product_id" => 604
 ],
 [
   "name" => "Patato",
   "product_id" => 550
 ]
]
```

Comment: Does the database hold duplicates? If not, then it shouldn't be returning multiple records. If you need a product more than once, fetch its data once and then reuse wherever you need.

Comment: @El_Vanja Yes. database will store multiple product_id as well. My use case is, user are able to select same product. Thats why the input will capture two `640`

Comment: @El_Vanja Reuse the data mean i need to foreach loop to get the result?

Comment: If the database really did hold two entries with the same `product_id`, then it would have returned them. Your use case isn't clear, or your database structure. By reuse I meant reuse the result array, not making multiple queries.